# Perform a nested for loop with RDD.map() in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm rather new to Spark and Scala and have a Java background. I have done some programming in haskell, so not completely new to functional programming.

I'm trying to accomplish some form of a nested for-loop. I have a RDD which I want to manipulate based on every two elements in the RDD. The pseudo code (java-like) would look like this:

```
// some RDD named rdd is available before this
List list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < rdd.length; i++){
   list.add(rdd.get(i)._1);
   for(int j = 0; j < rdd.length; j++){
      if(rdd.get(i)._1 == rdd.get(j)._1){
         list.add(rdd.get(j)._1);
      }
   }
}
// Then now let ._1 of the rdd be this list
```

My scala solution (that does not work) looks like this:

```
  val aggregatedTransactions = joinedTransactions.map( f => {
     var list = List[Any](f._2._1)
     val filtered = joinedTransactions.filter(t => f._1 == t._1)

     for(i <- filtered){
       list ::= i._2._1
     }

     (f._1, list, f._2._2)
  })
```

I'm trying to achieve to put item _2._1 into a list if ._1 of both items is equal.
I am aware that i cannot do any filter or map function within another map function. I've read that you could achieve something like this with a join, but I don't see how I could actually get these items into a list or any structure that can be used as list.

How do you achieve an effect like this with RDDs?

Comment: I think you need to state what you're trying to achieve more precisely (i.e. I don't think the Java code matches your stated intentions).  For starters, why don't you use case classes to define the objects you're working with?

Comment: In case you work with scala first time, I would strongly advice to spend some time playing with scala and especially with scala collections. hope thats helps

Comment: I could not use a scala collection for this, since collections cannot be serialized and therefore will throw an error on a spark system (due to the garbage collector running overtime..). This was indeed my first try.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input has the form `RDD[(A, (A, B))]` for some types `A, B`, and that the expected result should have the form `RDD[A]` - not a List (because we want to keep data distributed) - this would seem to do what you need:

```
rdd.join(rdd.values).keys
```

**Details**:

It's hard to understand the exact input and expected output, as the data structure (type) of neither is explicitly stated, and the requirement is not well explained by the code example. So I'll make some assumptions and hope that it will help with your specific case.

For the full example, I'll assume:

- Input RDD has type `RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))]`
- Expected output has the form `RDD[Int]`, and would contain a lot of duplicates - if the original RDD has the "key" X multiple times, each match (in `._2._1`) would appear once per occurrence of X as a key

If that's the case we're trying to solve - this `join` would solve it:

```
// Some sample data, assuming all ints
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, (1, 5)),
  (1, (2, 5)),
  (2, (1, 5)),
  (3, (4, 5))
))

// joining the original RDD with an RDD of the "values" -
// so the joined RDD will have "._2._1" as key
// then we get the keys only, because they equal the values anyway
val result: RDD[Int] = rdd.join(rdd.values).keys

// result is a key-value RDD with the original keys as keys, and a list of matching _2._1
println(result.collect.toList) // List(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: I realize now that I should have stated my question more concretely.
What I am trying to achieve is an RDD that holds aggregated edges.
._1 is the key that I want to join them on. 
The structure is (id, (src, dest)). Therefor I wanted to achieve a list of sources, while keeping only one id per RDD "row". 
So: (id, (list<src>, dest))

I'm still not completely sure how I can achieve this when looking at your code. Could you try to explain this?

Comment: That sounds very different from what this post describes (or what the Java code would do if it worked...) so I suggest you post a *new* question with the information in this comment, plus a sample INPUT and the expected OUTPUT. Someone (maybe me!) would then be able to help.